# Adding route to Ruby on Rails Spree Commerce app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I have the following relevant gems installed:

```
gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: '2-1-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git', 
:branch => '2-1-stable'
```

[A known problem](https://github.com/radar/spree_auth_devise/issues/19) (?) in Spree Commerce with spree_auth_devise is that when you click the logout link while on the admin page it does not work. You get the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/store/user/spree_user
         /logout"):
```

I am trying to solve this error. I know that the route [root]/logout works and provides a proper logout. Now I am trying to redirect the above link that does not work to the [root]/logout one (when you do the /logout get request from the admin page it works fine). The /logout routes to `spree/user_sessions#destroy`.

In `routes.rb` I tried adding the following:

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.prepend do
    get 'user/spree_user/logout', :to => 'spree/user_sessions#destroy'
end
```

but that still gives the same error.

How do I properly route the path user/spree_user/logout to the working logout action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem on a project where it wasn't cost effective to dig around. I fixed it by adding a redirect:

```
match "/store/user/spree_user/logout", :to => redirect('/store/logout')
```

Where 'store' is your Spree root.